# Unwanted deletion of TypeScript generated files by Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

When publishing with Visual Studio 2022 the following files get deleted: All of d.ts and tsBuildInfoFile files and all .js that are the result of previous TypeScript compilations.

This does not happen during a normal build with Visual Studio (doesn't matter if it's release or debug). When inspecting the Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file of the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package there are some entries that deal with the deletion of tsc compilation output e.g.:

```
<Target Name="TypeScriptDeleteCompilerOutput" ...
<Target Name="TypeScriptDeleteOutputFromOtherConfigs" ...
<Target Name="TypeScriptBuildModeClean" ...
```

I assume somehow it is possible to define for Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild to not run those cleaning TypeScript MSBuild targets (maybe inside my .csproj) during publishing, but how?

Versions are: VS 17.4.1 and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild NuGet package 4.8.4.

Comment: From the .targets file, looks like the targets have condition, you can set the value of the variable in properties group. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT That's right, but the BuildingProject and DesignTimeBuild conditions sound general so I thought there might be unwanted side effects if I set those. Regarding  TypeScriptBuildMode I think it will make run TypeScriptBuildModeClean.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, your project seems a C# project. MSBuild is the default build tool for .NET project, when you click 'publish', VS2022 should use MSBuild to do the publish operations. Basically, for common C# project, the operations that the VS2022 do when you click publish should be like this:

**`msbuild /t:publish /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/FolderProfile.pubxml`**

you can use this command to make it use release content of build:

**`msbuild /t:publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=output_directory ProjectName.csproj`**

Of course, if your project is .Net Core, .Net 5 or higher version; then you can use this command:

**`dotnet publish --configuration Release --output output_directory`**

The above is just some examples, you can specify the path you want.

For the targets you provided, you can check the conditions of them, and then add the properties to the `<PropertyGroup>` part of .csproj file. or using command like this:

**`msbuild <your_project>.csproj /p:TypeScriptBuildMode=true`**

properties:

[Compiler Options in MSBuild](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options-in-msbuild.html)

[TypeScriptBuildMode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#msbuild)

By the way, if possible, please provide the project type you are testing.

Comment: It's C# ASP.NET Core with some tsconfig files. If TypeScriptBuildMode is true there still seems to be cleaning (from TypeScriptBuildModeClean I think). It's probably not possible to totally prevent cleaning.